# Ruby on Rails 5 Nested comments not being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner in rails and trying to create a Reddit type blog page. Currently, I'm working on nested comments so the user is able to reply to comments. In my app I have forums, posts and comments. Creating posts and forums has worked perfectly, also posting comments until I tried nesting replies. My code looks like this (Forums and Users models/controllers have been omitted) :

My Comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end`
```

My Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :forum
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My posts_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
 @posts = Post.all
end

def show
 @post = find_post
end

def new
 @post = Post.new
end

def edit
 @post = find_post
end

def create
 @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
 @post = @forum.posts.create(post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
 redirect_to forum_path(@forum)
end

def update
 @post = find_post

 if @post.update(post_params)
  redirect_to forum_path
 else
  render 'show'
 end
end

def destroy
 @post = find_post
 @post.destroy

 redirect_to forum_path
end

private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
 end

private
 def find_post
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @forum.posts.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

My comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_commentable

 def index
  @comments = Comment.all
 end

 def new
  @comment = Comment.new
 end

 def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.create(comment_params.merge(user_id:        current_user.id))
  if @comment.save
   @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
   redirect_to forum_post_path(@post.forum_id, @post), notice: 'Your comment was successfully posted!'
  else
   redirect_to forum_post_path(@post.forum_id, @post), notice: 'error :('
  end
 end

 private
  def comment_params
   params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end

private
 def find_commentable
  @commentable = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]
  @commentable = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
 end
end
```

My views/comments/_comment:

```
<li>
<%= comment.content %>
<small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</small>

<h2>Add a Reply:</h2>
 <%= form_with(model: [ comment, comment.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a Reply" %><br/>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
 <% end %>
<ul>
  <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments if comment.comments.any? %>
</ul>
<%= link_to 'Back', forum_post_path(@forum, @post) %>
```

My views/post/show:

```
<small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago</small>

<h3>Comments</h3>

<ul>
 <%= render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @post.comments) if @post.comments.any?%>
</ul>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>

<%= form_with(model: [ @post, @post.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
<%= form.text_field :content, placeholder: "Add a comment" %><br/>
<%= form.submit "Add Comment" %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', forum_path(@forum) %>
<%= link_to 'All posts', forum_posts_path(@post.forum_id) %>
<%= link_to 'All comments', post_comments_path(@post) %>

</li>
```

My routes:

```
  resources :posts do
   resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments do
   resources :comments
  end
```

The first errors I kept getting were that every time I submitted a comment in `view/posts/show` the comment wouldn't create. Now, views/comments/_comment lifts the error:

```
Showing /example/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb where line #3 raised:

nil can't be converted to a Time value 

<small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</small>
```

after I submit a new comment. Any help regarding this error is appreciated or related to my main goal, I have been circling around this for a long time. Thanks!

Comment: Can you dump the log output with the error to make the errors more clear?

Comment: Also add your post controller please

Comment: @KartikeyTanna the code has been updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that new comment is initialized(for the comment which is being rendered) every time the partial is trying to render the comment.
Check out the following `byebug` output:

```
(byebug) pp comment.comments
[#<Comment:0x007f35ce11d900
  id: 5,
  content: "DEF",
  commentable_id: 4,
  commentable_type: "Comment",
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Wed, 30 May 2018 06:53:51 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 30 May 2018 06:53:51 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Comment:0x007f35ce2a3388
  id: nil,
  content: nil,
  commentable_id: 4,
  commentable_type: "Comment",
  user_id: nil,
  created_at: nil,
  updated_at: nil>]
```

This line is the culprit:

```
 <%= form_with(model: [ comment, comment.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
```

`comment.comments.build` initializes a new empty Comment which is your code then tries to render and throws the error as it does not have `created_at`.

And then the newly initialized comment is being rendered by the code.

Replacing `app/views/comments/_comment#13` with the following will resolve the issue:

```
  <%= render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.comments.where.not(content: nil)) if comment.comments.any? %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Posts do create as I can see them and have no problem with these. The error is with comments, so it's actually the line `<small>Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</small>` lifting the error.

Comment: @SebastianRicke I have changed my answer based on the data you provided.